# Error while compiling CoreNLP with OpenJDK 11.0.4

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am trying to compile CoreNLP sources using OpenJDK 11.0.4. 
I get:

```
[parsing started SimpleFileObject[.../CoreNLP/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process/package-info.java]]
[parsing completed 0ms]
[parsing started SimpleFileObject[.../CoreNLP/src/edu/stanford/nlp/sequences/SeqClassifierFlags.java]]
[total 1149ms]
compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=11.0.4, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavaTokenizer.readToken(JavaTokenizer.java:569)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.ensureLookahead(Scanner.java:102)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.token(Scanner.java:95)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.peekToken(JavacParser.java:254)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.peekToken(JavacParser.java:250)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term3(JavacParser.java:1196)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term2(JavacParser.java:859)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term1(JavacParser.java:830)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:786)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:766)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseExpression(JavacParser.java:717)
```

I am using maven-compiler-version plugin version 3.8.0 with source and target set to 1.8. 
  Any help in resolving this is appreciated.

Comment: I meant maven-compiler-plugin version 3.8.0.

Comment: have find the solution?

Comment: don't have a solution yet.

Comment: I got the code base to build by modifying SeqClassifierFlags.java.  11.0.4 compiler has an issue dealing with a large if-else-if.. statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `pom-java-11.xml` file for the `pom.xml` instead of the default `pom.xml` which supports Java 8.

Comment: I synced my source to the latest and tried using pom-java-11.xml. Now I get compilation errors in CoreNLP/src/edu/stanford/nlp/util/LuceneFieldType.java:[4,31] cannot find symbol symbol:   class IndexOptions
 --
 CoreNLP/src/edu/stanford/nlp/patterns/LuceneSentenceIndex.java:[71,25] constructor IndexWriterConfig in class org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig cannot be applied to given types;
  required: org.apache.lucene.util.Version,org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer
  found: org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length...etc.

Comment: Is a precompiled jar that is compatible with both JDK 11 & 8 available?